# Spring boot w/ arango: Store BigDecimal as number

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arangodb, arangodb-java

I'm trying to save a BigDecimal to arango db, but it stores it as a String. This creates a problems with sorting - I have to call `to_number`. Is there any possibility to tell arango to store big decimal as normal number?

Answer (score 0):

ArangoDB used exactly what you demand to serialize BigDecimals. But due to a precision loss (my guess) they changed that starting with [ArangoDB 4.4.0 released on April 19th 2018.](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/b0dd98a45dbdfa9ec3ad8cd12cb2022ce06f0568/ChangeLog.md?plain=1#L627)

Note: you (may) loose precision when you call Arangos "to_number". From the [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-type-cast.html#to_number):

> Strings are converted to their numeric equivalent if the string contains a valid representation of a number.